# GPG and keyservers: how do I mark a key as unused invalid?

Tags: security, encryption, privacy, pgp

I while ago I uploaded my key to the MIT keyserver.
Problem is, I lost my private key, and did not generate a revocation certificate. The key pair was generated with gpg < 2.1, so a revocation certificate was not created automatically either.
To make matters worse, I set the key to never expire.

Can I create a new pair (with the same name and email), upload it to the keyserver, and somehow mark the older key as invalid?

Comment: @Jens Erat in the answer to that question, two methods are mentioned: either Sign the old key with the new one and then revoke the signature. OR Create a key with a UID that warns about the deprecation and sign an old key with that. I want to know exaclty how I can do that, I don't have a lot of experience with this and I don't want to screw up and further clutter the key server

Comment: The answer is mostly telling "there is no proper way" and pretty much discusses all three alternatives as not really appropriate. None of them is properly marking the old key as "invalid". Accept the faith (until at some time probably far in the future) computing power is sufficient to brute-force the key pair, and start over with a new key making sure the same does not happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload a new key, but you can never delete or revoke an existing key.
If you could do so, you could create a key in the name of someone else and substitute his/her key.

But that is IMHO one of the biggest problems of the key servers: that they are accumulating more and more rubbish...

Comment: You can revoke existing keys and issue revocation certs to keyservers.  ([tutorial](https://www.hackdiary.com/2004/01/18/revoking-a-gpg-key/), [official faq](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/gnupg-faq.html#generate_revocation_certificate))